# Conflict in Hibernate 3.6 and 4.1

Tags: hibernate

Currently I am using Hibernate version 4.1.17_final in my current application. I am using Multi-Tenancy feature of hibernate in my application.
I have to integrate one another application into my current application. But that application using Hibernate 3.6 version. I integrated that application by copying jars from that application and pasted it into my WEB-INF/lib folder. I thought hibernate 4.1.17 version will have the compatibility. My requirement is like I have to get the data by using their API and display it in my application. But when I am trying to call any class method from that jar to get the data it is giving me following error.

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;`

and if I change the version to 3.6 of my current application so Multi-Tenancy feature will not work. Because it is available in 4.0 version.
Any help would be really appreaciable..Please guide me in this problem. I googled it but not found any specific way. I am using Maven for building and mapping dependancies.

Please let me know If you want more information.

Thanks & regards,
Parag737

Comment: can you post your pom file?, have you verified conflicted version?